# How to add 12 to a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Hi I have a string that contains the URL as in below

http://www.myurl.com/abc/asdd/asd/rwewe/saaa/all-makes?expanded=no&s=true&searchLimit=12&searchOffset=24

I am storing the URL in a js string as below

```
var backToSearch = $(location).attr('href');
//typeof(backToSearch);
```

I want to add 12 to searchOffset and then set it to cookie myCookie.

```
$.cookie('myCookie', backToSearch , {  path: '/' });
```

When 12 is added it will be like

http://www.myurl.com/abc/asdd/asd/rwewe/saaa/all-makes?expanded=no&s=true&searchLimit=12&searchOffset=36

How to add 12 to the string?

Comment: Adding 12 to the string just appends 12. I need it to be added!

Comment: I am adding the solution just in case it helps anybody else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about;

```
url = url.replace(/searchOffset=(\d+)/, function(a, b) {
    return "searchOffset=" + (parseInt(b, 10) + 12);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
function getURLParameter(name) { //get getURLParameter value
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null
}
var searchOffset = getURLParameter(searchOffset), //get Current value
    newSearchOffset = +searchOffset + 12; // set new value
var backToSearch = $(location).attr('href')
    .replace('searchOffset=' + searchOffset, 'searchOffset=' + newSearchOffset);
    //replace old value with new one
```

[String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global%5fObjects/String/replace)

[decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global%5fObjects/decodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 1):

Mine was a little bit more long winded than the rest I believe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var backToSearch = $(location).attr('href');
var split = backToSearch.split("searchOffset=");
var number = parseInt(split[1]);
number += 12;
var url = split[0] + "searchOffset=" + number.toString();
</script>
```

Comment: Yours is easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

If you have the searchOffset=24 parameter,
just get the value, parse it as number then add 12

```
parseInt(searchOffset)+12
```

Comment: If you read the author comment, you'll find that was exactly his problem.

Comment: Your comment (not an answer) does not tell him how to get the variable `searchOffset` that you reference, and it does not tell him how to update the querystring with the updated value.  This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used at the end is as below

```js
    var backToSearch = $(location).attr('href');
    backToSearch = backToSearch .replace(/searchOffset=(\d+)/,     function(a, b) {
    return "searchOffset=" + (parseInt(b, 10) + 12);
   })
```